# My headphones are picking up radio

Tags: headphones, interference

I recently got a new computer and as soon as I plugged in my headphones, I heard static coming in from only one side of my headphones. I unplugged my charger but I can still hear the radio, can anyone help me make it go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your computer properly grounded? If it's properly grounded you shouldn't have too many problems with stray RF. (You could check this in a number of  ways, but the easiest off the top of my head would be to check that the resistance between your case and a wall-outlet ground receptacle is close to zero)

If you still have a problem, buy an RF choke (I found a 5-pack on amazon for $5) and clip it on your headphone cable; you can also wrap the cable through it a few times for better noise suppression. (Incidentally, this is what the big round cylinder on most mouse cables is.)